# is there a way to pass basic auth from my SSO webproxy to an app which has form authentication only?

Tags: web

maybe some very simple webpage in-between?

I need this for this app:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-web-client-admin